# When you move the camera (phone) object moves with it (ARKit)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arkit

I'm working on Unity 3D with the ARKit plugin. Remaking the standard scene Example. My task is to put on the plane model home (still quite large). But when I create a large object it is not fixed on the plane and moves with the camera. What do I do to keep him in place? 
When placing small objects there are no problems.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;


namespace UnityEngine.XR.iOS
{
public class UnityARHitTestExample : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform m_HitTransform;
    public float maxRayDistance = 30.0f;
    public LayerMask collisionLayer = 1 << 10;  //ARKitPlane layer
    public GameObject home;

    private bool isDetecting;

    bool HitTestWithResultType (ARPoint point, ARHitTestResultType 
resultTypes)
    {
        List<ARHitTestResult> hitResults = 
UnityARSessionNativeInterface.GetARSessionNativeInterface 
().HitTest (point, resultTypes);
        if (hitResults.Count > 0) {
            foreach (var hitResult in hitResults) {
                Debug.Log ("Got hit!");
                m_HitTransform.position = 
UnityARMatrixOps.GetPosition (hitResult.worldTransform);
                m_HitTransform.rotation = 
UnityARMatrixOps.GetRotation (hitResult.worldTransform);
                Debug.Log (string.Format ("x:{0:0.######} y: 
{1:0.######} z:{2:0.######}", m_HitTransform.position.x, 
m_HitTransform.position.y, m_HitTransform.position.z));
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        isDetecting = true;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
#if UNITY_EDITOR   
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Ray ray = 
Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;
            home.SetActive(true);
            //we'll try to hit one of the plane collider 
gameobjects that were generated by the plugin
            //effectively similar to calling HitTest with 
ARHitTestResultType.ARHitTestResultTypeExistingPlaneUsingExtent
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, maxRayDistance, 
collisionLayer))
            {
                m_HitTransform.position = hit.point;
                Debug.Log(string.Format("x:{0:0.######} y: 
{1:0.######} z:{2:0.######}", m_HitTransform.position.x, 
m_HitTransform.position.y, m_HitTransform.position.z));

                m_HitTransform.rotation = hit.transform.rotation;
            }
        }
#else
        if (Input.touchCount > 0 && m_HitTransform != null)
        {
            var touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
            if ((touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began || touch.phase == 
TouchPhase.Moved) && isDetecting == true)
            {
                var screenPosition = 
Camera.main.ScreenToViewportPoint(touch.position);
                ARPoint point = new ARPoint {
                    x = screenPosition.x,
                    y = screenPosition.y
                };

                home.SetActive(true);

                // prioritize reults types
                ARHitTestResultType[] resultTypes = {

//ARHitTestResultType.ARHitTestResultTypeExistingPlaneUsingGeometry,

ARHitTestResultType.ARHitTestResultTypeExistingPlaneUsingExtent, 

//ARHitTestResultType.ARHitTestResultTypeExistingPlane,

ARHitTestResultType.ARHitTestResultTypeEstimatedHorizontalPlane, 

//ARHitTestResultType.ARHitTestResultTypeEstimatedVerticalPlane, 

ARHitTestResultType.ARHitTestResultTypeFeaturePoint
                }; 

                foreach (ARHitTestResultType resultType in 
resultTypes)
                {
                    if (HitTestWithResultType (point, resultType))
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                }
                isDetecting = false;
            }
        }
#endif

    }


  }
}
```

Comment: When you make a small object, does it also have this problem?  I am wondering if the problem is just that it can't find enough edges or other points to "fix" the bottom to ...

Comment: Yes, if you put a small object is all right.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you publish a code, please?

Comment: Thanks. Posted the code.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that this could just be because your object is actually 'behind' the real content in the scene (walls, ground etc).

Because ARKit (and ARCore) don't have occlusion if you place something behind a wall then it will actually just appear over top of it.

The result of this is that your content looks like it is moving! This can happen quite a lot, and is quite annoying.

To test, try load the model in a really large outdoor space.

(Note that I haven't properly read through your code so someone else may find a bug, but this is still a legitimate reason it might be causing it on top of that.)

Comment: Thanks. I tried what you said. Did not help ( the Object still moving behind the camera. Maybe there is some way to solve this problem?